# Unique solution to PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the wave equation $$\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial t^2}= c^2 \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$ 
where $u$ is the vertical height of the string. 
Given the following boundary conditions $u(0,t) = u(L,t) = 0$ and initial conditions $u(x,0) = f(x)$ , $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} (x, 0) = g(x)$.

Prove that the above system has a unique solution.

I was told to use conservation of energy to solve this problem, that is $d E/ d t = c^2( u_x(L,t) u_t (L,t) - u_x(0,t) u_t (0,t))$

I went with the standard approach of assuming two solutions $v, w$ to the above system, and tried to arrive to a contradiction. 
I am trying to achieve a stage where I can get to $v-w=0$, but I can't seem to get there. Simply plugging and subtracting in the PDE and the initial conditions doesn't seem to work. I am unsure of how to use energy conservation here. 
I know how to get to the solution using separation of variables, and considering positive, negative and zero eigenvalues and using Fourier series to get to a solution. Though, I doubt the question is asking for that... 
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Let $v_1$ and $v_2$ be your two solutions and note that $w = v_1 - v_2$ satisfy the PDE with all boundary conditions just being $=0$. Then consider the energy $E(t) = \int_0^L [w_t^2 + w_x^2] {\rm d}x$.

Comment: I did exactly that, but if $w$ does not satisfying the initial conditions, it is not a solution to the system right?

Comment: You assume you have two solutions $v_1$ and $v_2$. Then you use this to show that $w = v_1 - v_2$ satisfy the wave equation with initial/boundary conditions given by those of $v_1$ minus those of $v_2$ so for example $w(x,0) = f(x) - f(x) = 0$ etc. Thus the system that $w$ satisfy is $w_{tt} = c^2 w_{xx}$ with $w(x,0) = 0$ and $w_t(x,0) = 0$ and $w(0,t) = w(L,t) = 0$. All you need for the energy argument is that $w$ satisfy the wave equation (and that the BC are such that you can show $E'(t) \leq 0$)

Comment: How do you show $E'(t) \leq 0$

Comment: Here you can show $E'(t) = 0$ as energy is conserved with the given BC. You take the energy functional, compute the derivative and use the equation of motion to simplify. You should get $E'(t) = \ldots$ (what you have in the question) and these terms should vanish because of the BC. For example $u(0,t) = 0 \implies u_t(0,t) = 0$.